# asp.net C# retrieve data from sql according to passed querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, datareader

Assuming that the cardDetailsID is 5.

Looking at record number 5 in the cardDetails table of the database, one can see that its other fields include "bgcolour" and "borderstyle". Therefore, for this particular record I've got cardDetailsID = 5, bgcolour = blue, bordersytle= solid.

I want to be able to get the bgcolour and bordersyle settings (blue and solid) from the cardDetailsID.

This is the code so far. The value in the querystring is working (number "5" is being passed) but now how do I get the rest of the setting of the row?

```
    cardDetailsIDrv.Text = Request.QueryString["cardDetailsID"];
    cardDetailsIDrv.Visible = false;

    //create Connection
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]);


    //create Command
    SqlCommand getCardDetailsCMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM cardDetails WHERE cardDetailsID =" + Convert.ToInt32(cardDetailsIDrv.Text), myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();

    //create datareader
    SqlDataReader myReader = getCardDetailsCMD.ExecuteReader();

    //code works properly up till here


    try
    {
        //Using DataReader to retrieve info from the database and display it on the panel

        while (myReader.Read())
        { 
           //I'm guessing here is where I'm messing things up
           pnlCardps.BackColor = Color.FromName(myReader["bgcolour"].ToString());
           pnlCardps.BorderStyle = (BorderStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(BorderStyle), myReader["borderstyle"].ToString());

        }
    }

    finally
    {
        if (myReader != null)
        {
            myReader.Close();
        }

        if (myConnection != null)
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

PROBLEM SOLVED!!
All I had to do is tweak the code in the while loop to:

```
string bgColour = myReader["bgColour"].ToString();
pnlCardrv.BackColor = Color.FromName(bgColour);

string borderColour = myReader["borderColour"].ToString();
pnlCardrv.BorderColor = Color.FromName(borderColour);
```

Comment: What is the SQL query you are issuing? What error or other issue are you experiencing when you say it did not work?

Comment: Are the values being returned what you're expecting, i.e., "Red", "Blue", etc?

Comment: @marc_s There's no need to go bold text on the poor guy. I don't think he meant any harm. =)

Comment: @Yatrix I am not getting any errors, just simply the "blue background" and "solid border" are not being shown on the panel (pnlCardsps).

Comment: But the word "Blue" is being returned by your query, is what I'm asking. The query doesn't have to error for  you not to get what you want. I'm just making sure you're not getting a null value returned or "blue" instead of "Blue". I would guess that that the method is case-sensitive, but haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, you have to get the `detailsID` which is passed via the query string and then perform the query.

```
int id;
if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["detailsID"],out id))
{

string sql= string.Format("select .. from .. where id={0}",id);// using SqlParameter is much better and secure
// and execute your query and fetch the data reader
while(reader.Read())
{
 // bla bla bla
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've somewhat done that part already with an SQLConnection, an SQLCommand and an SQLDataReader. It's what I do in the while loop that is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.QueryString["detailsID"]` will get you the value of the query string variable.

```
if (Request.QueryString("detailsID") == null || Request.QueryString("detailsID").Length <= 0 || !int.TryParse(Request.QueryString("detailsID"), out detailsID) || MessageThreadID <= 0)
{
    //This is my standard exception, but you can handle it how you want.
    throw new Exception("Error: unable to load detailsID.  Request.QueryString.count: " + Request.QueryString.Count + " Request.QueryString(\"detailsID\"): " + Request.QueryString("detailsID"));
}
```

Comment: @Rika If this does not answer your question then you will need to show us how you are accessing the database to get the record.  Otherwise please accept an answer.